# All errors are not being displayed for form validation

Tags: php

I want to display a list of all the errors below but instead it is only displaying one error at a time, does anyone know why my code is not displaying a list of errors? Below is the code display the array to store the errors, the code for stating what happens if there is are no errors, and the code stating what happens if there are errors.

```
    <?php 

  $getcourseid = (isset($_POST['courseid'])) ? $_POST['courseid'] : '';
  $getcoursename = (isset($_POST['coursename'])) ? $_POST['coursename'] : '';
  $getduration = (isset($_POST['duration'])) ? $_POST['duration'] : '';

        $errors = array();


                  if (!$getcourseid){
                      $errors[] = "You must enter in Course's ID";
              }else if (!$getcoursename){
                  $errors[] = "You must enter in Course's Name";
              }else if (!$getduration){
                      $errors[] = "You must select Course's Duration";
                  }   

          if(!$errors) {

         $insertsql = "
        INSERT INTO Course
            (CourseNo, CourseName, Duration)
          VALUES
            (?, ?, ?)
        ";
        if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
          // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        }                                           

        $insert->bind_param("sss", $getcourseid, $getcoursename, $getduration);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();

         // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
    $query = "SELECT CourseNo FROM Course WHERE CourseNo = ?";
    // prepare query
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$getcourseid);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(); 
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $stmt->bind_result($dbCourseId);
    //get number of rows
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();  

              }  



            if(empty($errors)) {
                if ($numrows == 1){
               $errormsg = "<span style='color: green'>Course " . $getcourseid .  " - "  . $getcoursename . " has been Created</span>";
               $getcourseid = "";
               $getcoursename = "";
               $getduration = "";
            }else{
                $errormsg = "An error has occured, Course has not been Created";
            }
            } else {
                if (count($errors) > 0)
                {
                    foreach ($errors AS $Errors)
                    {
                        $errormsg = "{$Errors} <br>"; 
                    }
                }
            }     
        ?>

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION:**



    $form = "
    <form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'>
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Course ID:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='courseid' value='$getcourseid' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Course Name:</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='nameofcourse' name='coursename' value='$getcoursename' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Duration (Years):</td>
      <td>{$durationHTML}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type='submit' value='Create Course' name='createbtn' /></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </form>";

      echo $form;
```

The above form goes below the php code at the top of this question. Now what is happening is that the list of validation errors are all being displayed at the top of the form. But what I really want is each validation error to go below the form feature it is referring to.

E.g If I have not filled in the Course Id text input, then I want the validation error `"You must enter in Course's ID"` to be displayed below the Course Id text input.

If I have not filled in the Course Name text input, then I want the validation error `"You must enter in Course's Name"` to be displayed below the Course Name text input.

etc. What needs to be changed in code in order to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
      if (!$getcourseid){
          $errors[] = "You must enter in Course's ID";
       } 
     if (!$getcoursename){
         $errors[] = "You must enter in Course's Name";
      }
      if (!$getduration){
          $errors[] = "You must select Course's Duration";
      }
```

Comment: My bad it works, I had to change `$errormsg = "{$Errors} <br>"; ` to `echo "{$Errors} <br>"; `

Comment: Are you ok if I ask an additional question below the current question I have rather than me creating a new question as it deals with validation still?

Comment: @user1881090 yup ... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php but not as comment since if there will too many comment it will automatically flaged

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!$getcourseid)
{
   $errors[] = "You must enter in Course's ID";
} 
if (!$getcoursename)
{
   $errors[] = "You must enter in Course's Name";
} 
if (!$getduration)
{
   $errors[] = "You must select Course's Duration";
}
```

Comment: My bad it works, I had to change `$errormsg = "{$Errors} <br>"; ` to `echo "{$Errors} <br>"; `

Comment: I have included additional question in question

Answer (score 1):

I've not completed code related to duration that you need to figure out I gave you an logic here for both inputs courseid and coursename.

```
    <?php 


    $errors = array();
    $getcourseid    = "";
    $getcoursename  = "";
    $errormsg = "";
        if($_POST)
        {
            $getcourseid    = $_POST['courseid'];
            $getcoursename  = $_POST['coursename'];
            if (!$getcourseid){
                  $errors['course_id'] = "You must enter in Course's ID";
            }if (!$getcoursename){
              $errors['course_name'] = "You must enter in Course's Name";
            }
        }



      if(!$errors && $_POST) {

     $insertsql = "
    INSERT INTO Course
        (CourseNo, CourseName, Duration)
      VALUES
        (?, ?, ?)
    ";
    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }                                           

    $insert->bind_param("sss", $getcourseid, $getcoursename, $getduration);

    $insert->execute();

    if ($insert->errno) {
      // Handle query error here
    }

    $insert->close();

     // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
$query = "SELECT CourseNo FROM Course WHERE CourseNo = ?";
// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("s",$getcourseid);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbCourseId);
//get number of rows
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows();  

          }  

$getcourseid = (!empty($getcourseid))?$getcourseid:"";
$getcoursename = (!empty($getcoursename))?$getcoursename:"";
$durationHTML  = (!empty($durationHTML))?$durationHTML:"";


$error_c_id = (!empty($errors['course_id']))?$errors['course_id']:"";
$error_c_name = (!empty($errors['course_name']))?$errors['course_name']:"";

$form = "
<form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>Course ID:</td>
  <td><input type='text' name='courseid' value='".$getcourseid."' />".$error_c_id."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Course Name:</td>
  <td><input type='text' id='nameofcourse' name='coursename' value='".$getcoursename."' />".$error_c_name."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Duration (Years):</td>
  <td>{$durationHTML}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type='submit' value='Create Course' name='createbtn' /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>";

  echo $form;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I have included if isset(...) code at top of php code in my question, does that mean I won't need you if ($_POST) method? Also do I need the `$getcourseid = (!empty($getcourseid))?$getcourseid:"";` and similar lines?

Comment: Please check my latest code. and yes you need that because your Error display seems off I could see notice errors at my end. That's what I've added those lines. Yes, I didn't saw your changes you did that in right way.

Comment: Hi, it is ok if I just use the if isset() code I have at top of my php page, that causes no problems with notices. Thank you very much. Obviously upovted answer. Btw it displays the error messages on top of form as well as next to each form feature.